# How to have different number of columns per row in table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am trying to build a table like the one of the image. I have tried with the \multicolumn method, however, I find struggles to pass from a row with 4 columns to the next one with 3. Any idea how to build it?

I have reviewed other solutions in the forum, but all goes from 4 to 2, 6 to 2/2/2 or similar. I have yet not seen one going from 4 to 3.

Here is the code I am using:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
%\cline{1-1} \cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Characteristics} & & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Categories} \\
\cline{0-1} \cline{4-7} \cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
1 & Focus & & Research Outcomes & Research Methods & Theories & Applications \\ \cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
2 & Goal & & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}{l|c|r} Integration & Criticism & Central issue\end{tabular}} \\
\cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
3 & Organization & & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}{l|c|r}  Historical & Conceptual & Methodological\end{tabular}} \\
\cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
4 & Perspective & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Neutral representation} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Espousal of position} \\ \cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
5 & Audience & & Specialized scholars & General scholars & Practitioners /Politicians & General Public \\ 
\cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
6 & Coverage & & Exhaustive & Exhaustive and selective & Representative & Central / pivotal \\
\cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}

\end{tabular}
\caption{Taxonomy of literature reviews based on Cooper method \footcite{Cooper1988OrganizingReviews}}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Thanks in advance.

Desired output

[image: Table to build]

Output of my code

[image: Code output]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Show what you tried, and people will suggest modifications.

Comment: Thanks. I just added the output of the code and result.

Comment: Thanks for posting your code.  For future reference, if you also include the `\documentclass` and `\begin/\end{document}`, then we can paste what you give us into a new document and see exactly what you're seeing (but not exactly, since you've gotten to 3.2 and a footnote that aren't related to your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
 \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ONE}&
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{TWO}&
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{THREE}&
 \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{FOUR}\\
\hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{one}&
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{two}&
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{three}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Just make sure your tabular has enough columns for all possible cell spans.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take with `tabularray`. The syntax is a bit heavy at first, but it's very convenient to play with it afterwards to adjust to taste.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={*{9}{c}},
    cell{1}{1}={c=2}{c, gray},
    cell{1}{4}={c=6}{c, gray},
    cell{1}{1,4}={fg=white},
    cell{3}{4}={bg=lightgray},
    cell{3}{5,7}={c=2}{c},
    cell{3}{9}={bg=lightgray},
    cell{4}{4}={bg=lightgray},
    cell{5}{6}={bg=lightgray},
    cell{4-5}{4,6,8}={c=2}{c},
    cell{6}{4}={c=3}{c, bg=lightgray},
    cell{6}{7}={c=3}{c},
    vline{1-10}={1,3-6}{solid},
    hline{1-7}={1,2,4-9}{solid},
    row{1,3-6}={ht=0.5cm},
    row{2}={ht=0.1cm},
    rows={m},
    stretch=0
    }
Characteristic & & & Categories\\
\ \\
1 & Focus & & {Research\\ outcome} & {Research\\ methods} & & Theories & & Applications\\
2 & Goal & & Integration & & Criticism & & Central issue\\
3 & Organization & & Historical & & Conceptual & & Methodological\\
4 & Perspective & & Neutral representation & & & Espousal of position\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

I did only the first four rows, but there's nothing new in the others.
[image: result]

Comment: Thanks! interesting to see another way to build tables.

Answer (score 0):

See below for updated version

---

### Version 1

@David Carlisle Thank you for your quick answer.

For whoever might be interested, here is how I made it.

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{616161} \textcolor{white}{Characteristics}} & & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{616161} \textcolor{white}{Categories}} \\
    \cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
    1 & Focus & & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Research Outcomes & Research Methods & Theories & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Applications \\ \cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
    2 & Goal & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Integration} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Criticism} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Central issue} \\ \cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
    3 & Organization & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Historical} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Conceptual} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Methodological} \\ \cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
    4 & Perspective & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Neutral representation} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Espousal of position} \\ \cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
    5 & Audience & & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Specialized scholars & General scholars & Practitioners /Politicians & General Public \\ 
    \cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
    6 & Coverage & & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Exhaustive & Exhaustive and selective & Representative & Central / pivotal \\
    \cline{0-1} \cline{4-7}
    
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Taxonomy of literature reviews based on Cooper method \footcite{Cooper1988OrganizingReviews}}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

[image]

---

### Version 2

update:

Thanks to @Rmano for the tips

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{ccc*{12}{wc{1cm}}}
    \cline{0-1} \cline{4-15}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{616161} \textcolor{white}{Characteristics}} & & \multicolumn{12}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{616161} \textcolor{white}{Categories}} \\
    \cline{0-1} \cline{4-15}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Focus} & & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{Research Outcomes} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{Research Methods} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{Theories} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Applications} \\
    \cline{0-1} \cline{4-15}

    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Goal}  & & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Integration} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Criticism} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Central issue} \\ \cline{0-1} \cline{4-15}
    
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Organization} & & \multicolumn{4}{|c}{Historical} & \multicolumn{4}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Conceptual} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Methodological} \\ 
    \cline{0-1} \cline{4-15}
    
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Perspective} & & \multicolumn{6}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Neutral representation} & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Espousal of position} \\ 
    \cline{0-1} \cline{4-15}
    
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Audience} & & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Specialized scholars} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{General scholars} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{Practitioners / Politicians} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{General Public} \\
    \cline{0-1} \cline{4-15}
    
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{6} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Coverage} & & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Exhaustive} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{Exhaustive and selective} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{Representative} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Central / pivotal} \\
    \cline{0-1} \cline{4-15}
    &&&&&&&&&&&&&& \\
    
    \end{tabular}}
    \caption{Taxonomy of literature reviews based on Cooper method \footcite{Cooper1988OrganizingReviews}}
    \label{tab:slr_taxonomy}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: To have both the 4-columns row and the 3-columns row "equispaced', you should go for the least common multiple for the number of `c` in the "categories" blocks; in this case, `{|c|c|*12{c|}}` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will implement it.

Comment: Well, and make them fixed width... Mmhh. I'll think about it; my first suggestion is too naive.

Comment: I just figured. In theory works fine, but since the cell width is not fixed, it is not uniform. I have to set the cell width to fix it.

Comment: Yes. No time to try it now, but `*12{wc{1cm}|}` should do the trick.

Comment: but this is a simple 4 column table with some cells spaning 2 colums, it doesn't use at all the layout you show in the question with overlapping cell spans, which, as I showed in my answer, requires  at least 6 columns.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!  `\begin{tabular}{ccc|*{12}{wc{1cm}|}}`. I did have a problem at the end. If I do not add (an empty row) `&&&&&&&&&&&&&& ` at the end, the whole format does not work. However, by adding it, works fine.

Comment: yes the `1&2...` row in my answer has a similar effect. An unfortunate "optimisation" in tex's table layout removes column boundaries that are not used, so if all cells are spanning cells it can sometimes need a fake row to ensure all intended columns are generated

Comment: Good to know that was not a total mistake from my side. Once more, Thanks!